# docker-compose.yml not working for logstash giving error '::HostUnreachableError'

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, logstash

I have the following files in my folder structure:

```
C:.
|   .env
|   docker-compose.yml
|
+---elasticsearch
|   \---config
|           elasticsearch.yml
|
\---logstash
    +---config
    |       log4j2.configuration
    |       log4j2.properties
    |       logstash.conf
    |       logstash.yml
    |       pipelines.yml
    |
    +---data
    |   |   .lock
    |   |   sample.csv
    |   |   uuid
    |   |
    |   +---dead_letter_queue
    |   \---queue
    +---logs
    \---pipeline
```

In my `docker-compose.yml` the configuration is as follows:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  logstash:
    # image: sebp/elk
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.12.0
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
      - "ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}"
      - "ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}"
      - "ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}"
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - ./logstash/config:/usr/share/logstash/config
      - ./logstash/data:/usr/share/logstash/data
      - ./logstash/pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline
      - ./logstash/logs:/usr/share/logstash/logs
    networks:
      - elastic

volumes:
  elasticsearch_data:

networks:
  elastic:
```

My host and user name and password is stored in the .env file. In the `logstash.yml` my configuration is:

```
http.host: "0.0.0.0"
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.hosts: "${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}"
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username: "${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}"
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password: "${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}"
```

My `pipelines.yml` configuration is:

```
- pipeline.id: my_pipeline
  path.config: "/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.conf"
```

The configuration for `logstash.conf` is:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/usr/share/logstash/data/sample.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}

filter {
  csv {
    separator => ","
    columns => ["User_Id","First_Name"]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}"
    user => "${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}"
    password => "${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}"
    index => "sample_csv-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

When I run the command `docker-compose -f .\docker-compose.yml up -d` and check the logs I get the following error for logstash:

```
Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[https://my-user-login:myPassword@myhost.ca:9200/]}}

2023-05-11 10:58:13 14:58:13.525 [LogStash::Runner] WARN  logstash.licensechecker.licensereader - Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"https://my-user-login:myPassword@myhost.ca:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [https://my-user-login:myPassword@myhost.ca:9200/][Manticore::ClientProtocolException] PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"}
```

I edited out my host and user from the logs for obvious privacy reasons. Any advice would be appreciated thanks!

Tried running logstash but got error

Comment: The error states `unable to find valid certification path to requested target`. [This thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/error-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path/122304) should be able to help you

Comment: what are you trying to do? are you trying to inject data(csv file) to Elasticsearch docker cluster?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to injest data to elastic-docker-cluster @FarkhodAbdukodirov.

Comment: I tried the thread you sent @Val but that didn't resolve the issue I set the following values to the `logstash.yml` :

`
http.host: "0.0.0.0"
output.elasticsearch.hosts: ["${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}"]
output.elasticsearch.username: "${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}"
output.elasticsearch.password: "${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}"
output.elasticsearch.ssl.enabled: true
output.elasticsearch.ssl.certificate_verification: false
`